# Java Codelab While statements

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Could someone explain why when I enter -99, the program doesn't stop?
When I enter -99 for the 1st input, the program stops but if I enter 1 first and then -99 second, the program does not stop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class TESTTEST {
       public static void main(String [] args) {
         // creates the scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        int max=0;
        int min=0;
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer (-99 to stop): ");
          number = input.nextInt();
          {
while (number != -99) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer (-99 to stop): ");
          number = input.nextInt();

         if (number> max ){
             number = max;  
         }
          else if (number<max ) {
                 number = min;
           }
        }

        System.out.println("max value is " +max);
        System.out.println("min value is "+min);

    }
}
   }
```

Comment: number is rewritted to min or max if number is not 0

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how would I change it  so that didnt happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted `number` and `max` / `min`

```
if (number> max ){
         number = max;  //Since max = 0, number turns into 0
     }
      else if (number<max ) {
             number = min; //Same thing here
       }
    }

    System.out.println("max value is " +max);
    System.out.println("min value is "+min);

}
```

Switch them:

```
if (number> max ){
         max = number;
     }
      else if (number<max ) {
             min= number;
       }
    }

    System.out.println("max value is " +max);
    System.out.println("min value is "+min);

}
```